# How to insert a copy of a string into another string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, replace

So, here is the function:

```
int strinsert(char *dst, int len, const char *src, int offset)
```

I need to insert a copy of my `src` string into the string called `dst` from the position `offset`.
The argument `len` specifies the number of characters reserved for the array `dst`.

the important part of the code:

```c
int strinsert(char *dst, int len, const char *src, int offset)
{
    strncpy(dst, src+offset, len);
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf+len, src);
    len += strlen(src) ;
    strcpy(buf+len, dst+offset); 
    strcpy(dst, buf);
    
    return 1;
}
```

Still feels kind of off...

Edit: Before someone misunderstood, I am just teaching myself how to program in C and I found this exercise. Btw, I didn't really found some good learning material for one- and two-dimensional arrays, could someone be so kind and post some?

Comment: That's the function's prototype not the function definition

Comment: What is your question? Did you try anything?

Comment: @VusP: this was my result of my edit - fixed

Comment: Shall we infer the question from this, because right I'm inferring it says "Will you do this so I don't have to?" Show what you did, what it is giving you, and why you think it may be doing so.

Comment: I don't obligatory need to do this, i'm just teaching myself "how to C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve the problem?

```c
int strinsert(char *dst, int len, const char *src, int offset) 
{
    char temp [MAX_SIZE];

    strncpy(temp, dest+offset, strlen(dest+offset));
    strncpy(dest+offset, src, strlen(src));
    strcat (dest+offset+strlen(src), temp);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Obviously, the above code doesn't have any error checking, and the temp can be malloced etc.

Comment: It will overwrite dest, and OP wants to insert in the middle

Comment: This doesn't do *anything* like what the OP wants. The OP wants the content at the specified index of the destination to be right-shifted to make room for the inserted source. This blasts over the destination from an offset within the source. I.e, it preserves nothing, and copies the wrong data.

Comment: if you copy something in to a buffer, obviously it will overwrite what is there in the buffer. Did he mean to say, overwrite the source? in that case, memmove() is best.

Comment: He meant what i wrote. Make room for the source string to be copied to a specific staring index of the destination, moving current destination content further down the string so as to lose *no* data. `dst="ABCDE"`, `src="123"`, `offset=2`. The result after insertion is `"AB123CDE"`. The purpose of the `len` argument is to prevent you from overwriting beyond end-of-dst, though the behavior in that case was not specified.

Comment: @whozcraid and mvp: edited my answer after your comments. I didn't understand the question correctly. Now does it look like a solution?

Comment: There is no need for a complete copy at al. And there is no need to use a temporary storage. Just 2 lines are needed!

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit painful, but you really have to contruct a new string as you can't really shuffle bits of memory around so easily and I don't think there is a library function to do this (is there??). Somthing like this:

```
int strinsert(char *dst, int len, const char *src, int offset)
{
    char *new_string = new char[len];
    int remaining = len;

    // Check offset is not to long (+1 for null)
    if (offset >= remaining)
        offset = remaining;

    // copy the pre-string from dest
    strncpy(new_string, dest, offset);
    // Calulate the remaining space
    remaining -= offset;

    // Add the insert string (with max chars remaining)
    strncat(new_string, src, remaining);
    // calc remaining space
    remaining -= strlen(src);

    // Add the post-string from dest (with max chars remaining)
    strncat(new_string, dest, remaining);

    // Finally copy the new_string into dest
    strncpy(dest, new_string, len);

    // free the memory
    delete [] new_string;
}
```

Note: You probably need to do a better job of calculating the remaining space incase it goes negative...

Edit: replaced variable length array (illegal ... oops) with mem allocation

Comment: True... infact you can just use the *dst location to build the string if you're careful :), for clarity I thought it easier just to build a new string up... for that I needed to alloc some space for it, or otherwise use hardcoded `char somthing[MAX_NUM]` which I don't didn't want to do.

Comment: You don't need to be careful :) Just use memmove and overlapping areas will be handled correct. See my version... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strncpy()`, which is a function of `string.h` library. It copies first `num` characters of `source` string to `destination` string.

char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );

But in your case, you need a third string because you can not expand your destination array. You can copy substring (from beginning to offset) of destination array into this third array and concatenate the rest. So you need to do something like this:

```
char *dst = "ThisIsMyHomework";
char *src = "Not";
char finalString[50];
int offset = 6; //Assume we want to insert "Not" string between "ThisIs" and "MyHomework". So we want src array to start from 6th index of dst array.

strncpy(finalString, dst, offset); //finalString="ThisIs"
finalString[offset] = '\0'; //For finalString, you have to add "\0" manually because strcat will append other strings from 50. index of array if you don't
strcat(finalString, src); //finalString="ThisIsNot"
strcat(finalString, dst + offset); //finalString="ThisIsNotMyHomework"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void strinsert(char *dst, size_t len, const char *src, size_t offset) 
{
  size_t iLenDst = strlen(dst),
         iLenSrc = strlen(src);

  // Some error handling
  if (iLenDst+iLenSrc+1>len)  
  {
    ASSERT(FALSE):
    return;
  }

  // restrict to max length
  if (offset>iLenDst)
    offset = iLenDst;

  // Make room incl. trailing \0
  memmove(dst+offset+iLenSrc,dst+offset,iLenDst-offset+1);
  // Insert new
  memcopy(dst+offset,src,iLenSrc);
}
```